# Append a series as a column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series marks looks like

```
Marks
 95
 85
 75
 88
```

I also have a dataframe,df, with id

```
ID
129 
1
398
311
329
```

I want to add marks in my dataframe. So I wrote following code

df['Marks']=marks
But my `df.head()` is returning

```
ID     Marks
129     NaN
1       NaN
398     NaN
311     NaN
329     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

Marks = [95, 85, 75, 80]

# creating the dataframe of IDs
array = {'ID': [129, 1, 398, 311]}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)

# Converting the series
dfmarks = pd.Series(Marks, name="marks")
# combining the two dataframes
df = pd.concat([df, dfmarks], axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

marks = pd.Series([95, 85, 75, 88])
df = pd.DataFrame([129, 1, 398, 311, 329], columns=["ID"])
df["Marks"] = marks
df.set_index("ID")
```

This will return the DataFrame with only 1 Nan (in the last row) due to the lenght difference between `df` and `marks`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
In [828]: df.loc[:, 'Marks'] = marks

In [829]: df
Out[829]: 
    ID  Marks
0  129   95.0
1    1   85.0
2  398   75.0
3  311   88.0
4  329    NaN
```